# How to disallow JSX syntax in JavaScript files (.js extension)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsx

I would like to make sure that JavaScript files (with `js` extension) in VS Code contain valid JavaScript syntax only.

Is it possible to disallow JSX syntax for `.js` files in VS Code?

Ideally of course I would like to still allow the JSX syntax for `.jsx` files.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "disallow"? Are you talking about not showing syntax highlighting, which is maybe something you'd configure in the IDE, or actually having warnings/errors, which seems more like a responsibility of your linting or build process?

Comment: JSX syntax typically found in a `render` function should produce an error since it is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: An error from... what? Are you using linting, is that configured correctly? Does your build step reject it? You haven't really clarified what role you want VSCode to play.

Comment: JSX syntax should be underlined in red like any invalid JavaScript code. I do not have a problem, I just want to be alerted in the editor when a JavaScript file contains invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe to be clear I am not talking about execution time, only about hints in the editor. If the system is properly configured for JSX it **should** execute. But unless I explicitly allow it in a project I would like VS Code to alert me that JSX syntax is not valid JavaScript (in a `.js` file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`react/jsx-filename-extension` rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md) of [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).

By default it only allows JSX inside `*.jsx` files so you will have an error/warning (depending on how you configure it) when it detects JSX in a file where it shouldn't be.